# HUAWEI AppLinking : Getting error code: 204865584 message: the android packageName does not have permission

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I'm integrating the codelab of AppLinking service. I followed every steps, which is mentioned in the docs/codelab.

While running the app I'm getting below error:

error code: 204865584

message:  [AppGalleryConnectLinkManageService]the android packageName does not have permission

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you have applied for URL Prefix or not , for more details please follow below links:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-applinking-getstarted-android-0000001054594767

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-applinking-urlprefix-0000001060148052

Answer (score 0):

The problem seen when creating link is caused by missing app in the AppGallery Connect. Please create the app in the AGC when setup Applink. You need this app to be added to AGC before things could function.
[image]